# Calling Javascript Functions and getting response back from Javascript file in android?

Tags: android, ios

I am working with iOS and Android Application. I have a Javascript file in which i have all the functions. I need to use these functions in both the platforms.

for example: I have a function 'purchaseItem()' in Javascript which i have to call from iOS or Android and want to get the callback from JavaScript,if item is purchased or not.

Is it possible to directly use the Javascript methods from native platforms. With this option I need not to integrate these JS functions in native and these can easily be reused.

I do not want to open a HTML page in webview to use its methods. I only want to call javascript methods simply and get callbacks for them.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can run a piece of Javascript as below. Replace `alert('Hello!')` with whatever you want to execute.

```
WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web_view);
webView.loadUrl("javascript:alert('Hello!')");
```

Comment: All the functions are in Javascript file. For Example: clickme() function in JS file.

Comment: You can create an invisible WebView and setup some HTML file with `loadData()` to load the JS file, then call `loadUrl("javascript:clickme()")`.